# C# pass property

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a class `UserPane l: Panel`. I do so.

```
 private bool AutoSize_ = true;
    public bool AutoSize
    {
        get
        {
            return AutoSize_;
        }
        set
        {
            AutoSize_ = value;
        }
    }
```

But when I change `Autosize_ still` returns are always true. How to make that value correctly transmitted.

Comment: *How to make that value correctly transmitted.* Post a minimally reproducible example so we can see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Please be more specific, your code seems alright

Comment: The problem is that `Panel` contains a definition for `AutoSize`, try overriding the property `public override bool AutoSize {...`.

Comment: I change AutoSize False in construction. But after debug change True.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria You're correct but What OP is going to do overriding `AutoSize`? If backing field is used he'll spoil the feature of `AutoSize`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel you're right, but it's not clear what he want to attain.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria yes, I'll say none of the answers below are helpful. They're not pointing in right direction.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel yes I think that too. By the question the real problem is why "returns are always true". Correct?

Comment: You should tell what you're trying to acheive to get help. Don't override `AutoSize` as all the answers say. Tell your problem what you're trying to do? Will try to help. If you override `AutoSize` and use a backing field you're spoiling the `AutoSize` feature of `Panel`

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria Of course. if that is the question then answer should be like this *You're shadowing AutoSize property, try to change the property name* That's it. Suggesting to override `AutoSize` and use backing field is pushing on to **pit of despair**

Comment: @SriramSakthivel hahaha sure, I've pointed out the "overriding" issue because I suspect it can be related with the problem, but it's only a suspect and maybe incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

The Panel class already have a property [AutoSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.panel.autosize.aspx).
You define a new Property with the same name. Check your warnings, you must have the following :

> warning CS0114: 'UserPanel.AutoSize' hides inherited member 'System.Windows.Forms.Panel.AutoSize'.  To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.

When you are calling the `AutoSize` property of `UserPanel`, you are in fact calling the property of the superclass `Panel`. So your field `AutoSize_` will never get changed.

Act accordingly to the warning :

```
public class UserPanel : Panel
{
    private bool AutoSize_ = true;
    public override bool AutoSize
    {
        get
        {
            return AutoSize_;
        }
        set
        {
            AutoSize_ = value;
        }
    }
}
```

On a side note, why do you want to change the already working AutoSize functionnality? Are you sure this is what you need?

Comment: +1 For what I assume was building WinFormsApplication489 and getting the warning message.

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the property, because it is already defined in `Panel`.

```
    public override bool AutoSize {
       get {
          return base.AutoSize;
       }
       set {
          base.AutoSize = value;
       }
    }
```

Isn't the compiler giving you the warning over this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing something like this.

```
 public partial class myPanel : Panel
        {
            private bool AutoSize_ = true;
            public bool AutoSize
            {
                get
                {
                    return AutoSize_;
                }
                set
                {
                    AutoSize_ = value;
                }
            }
    }
```

You are hiding `Panel`s `AutoSize` property. You should override this property. You can override it to return the base value (which actually does not do much).

```
public override bool AutoSize
        {
            get
            {
                return base.AutoSize;
            }
            set
            {
                base.AutoSize = value;
            }
        }
```

Or maybe you can do some custom work there.

```
public override bool AutoSize
        {
            get
            {
                //return custom value
            }
            set
            {
                //set some custom value
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have that class

```
class P : Panel
{
    bool AutoSize_ = true;
    public bool AutoSize
    {
        get
        {
            return AutoSize_;
        }
        set
        {
            AutoSize_ = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And then you create an instance and change the value of AutoSize like this:

```
var p = new P();

p.AutoSize = true;
```

This should work fine (at least in my tests), the problem arise when you do something like this:

```
var p2 = (Panel)p;

p2.AutoSize = false; // this change the AutoSize property of the Panel not the property of the derived class P
```

If this isn't your case then no idea what happens.